# When bending a cylinder while posing an armature, some surfaces are flat and the mesh doesn't keep it's volume

Tags: rigging, armature, vertices, pose-mode

I am making a stethoscope that bends smoothly like a curve this is before posing
[image: Before posing]
After posing this is the result after bending two bones at the position I want them to be.
[image]

This is before in the side view
[image]
After
[image]

I want the curve to be smooth like a noodle not, misshapen flat, when I try rigging, sometimes the curve bends backwards. How do I fix this?

Comment: I want the curve to be smooth like a noodle not, misshapen flat, when I try rigging, sometimes the curve bends backwards, how to i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a bendy bone? They can bend like a noodle but only work in Blender. Here is an example: https://youtu.be/RGQeLhecfHw (If you want to export it to a game engine you need to convert them.)